# VB.NET ContextMenuStrip dynamic subitems. How to add event on each subitems?

Tags: vb.net

how can I add an event or get the text of the subitem of the contextmenustrip control after I clicked the subitem?

Here's my code:

```
Try
        enrollment_conn.Open()
        command = New SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT Section FROM dbo.Enrollees WHERE Grade = '" & Main.Enrollees_Cbx_grade.Text & "' AND Strand = '" & Main.Enrollees_Cbx_strand.Text & "' AND School_Year = '" & Main.Enrollees_Cbx_sy.Text & "' AND Enrolled = 'Yes'", enrollment_conn)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader

        Main.Enrollees_CMS_enrolleesList.Items.Clear()
        Dim tm = New ToolStripMenuItem("Filter")
        Main.Enrollees_CMS_enrolleesList.Items.Add(tm)
        While reader.Read
            tm.DropDownItems.Add(reader.Item("Section").ToString)

        End While
        enrollment_conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbExclamation)
    End Try
```

The code above adds a Toolstripitem called Filter and when I right click my datagridview. The item Filter shows and has subitems which I added by using a query. The question is how can I get the text or add an event to the subitems? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Add` method that you're using here is overloaded:

```
tm.DropDownItems.Add(reader.Item("Section").ToString)
```

You should use the overload that lets you specify a `Click` event handler:

```
tm.DropDownItems.Add(reader.Item("Section").ToString, Nothing, AddressOf MenuItem_Click)
```

The third argument is a delegate to the event handler method.  If you're not comfortable writing that from scratch yourself, the simplest option is to let the IDE create one for you.  Simply double-click a menu item in the designer and an event handler will be generated in the usual way.  You can then delete the `Handles` clause from the end of the declaration and change the name to something more generic.  You can then access the menu item that was clicked via the `sender` parameter, which is always a reference to the object that raised the event:

```
Private Sub MenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim menuItem = DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)

    'Use menuItem here.
End Sub
```

If you need data for each menu item then you can assign it to the `Tag` property when you create it, e.g.

```
tm.DropDownItems.Add(reader.Item("Section").ToString,
                     Nothing,
                     AddressOf MenuItem_Click).Tag = reader.Item("Data")
```

and then get it back again in the event handler:

```
Private Sub MenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim menuItem = DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)
    Dim data = menuItem.Tag

    'Use data here.
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot tomorrow.. Thank you for sharing your knowledge and suggestions.

Comment: Hi your suggestion worked like a charm! I was able to get the information of the items of the toolstrip menu.. I rewrote this line of code:tm.DropDownItems.Add(reader.Item("Section").ToString, Nothing, AddressOf Main.MenuItem_Click).Tag = reader.Item("Section")... In the event method I just used the menuItem.Tag to get the data... Thank you so much I've been searching this solution yesterday for 4 hours.. You saved my work.